# Use same app data with another user (on Android 10)

Tags: android-10, multi-user

I have a Samsung Tablet running Android 10. My kid uses a "restricted user" (password-protected) to play etc.

Now, since the Lego BOOST app is also installed on this restricted user account, I would like to make it possible for him to use the tablet without me unlocking the user - my boy does not know the password and I don't want him to know ... but specifically for the Lego BOOST app I would like him to be able to use it without me being around.

So, in technical terms, I want to "share" all his user data (already unlocked data in the app) with another user account which would NOT be password-protected - or with a password I can tell him.

Is it possible to share the same app data between 2 users? Or, alternatively, is it possible to "move"/transfer the app data to another user account?

Comment: ON a rooted device may be. On an unrooted even migrating the data from one user to another is difficult as as far as I remember `adb backup` only works for the primary user. Also keep in mind that after a device reboot always the primary user have to login.